# Disable ActionBar button dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want  to disable the "attachment" button when there is no attachment is the page user loads.
I searched every stack overflow suggestion but I think I'm getting something wrong.
What I did is:

- set a boolean to find if there are attachments.
- call invalidateOptionsMenu();
- try to disable the action bar button

  ```
  @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.inpostmenu, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

  if (attachments) {
      menu.findItem(R.id.attach).setEnabled(!attachments);

  }
  }
  ```

I get an **Unreachable Statement** error on

> menu.findItem(R.id.attach).setEnabled(!attachments);

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: just put return statement after if block

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov It doesn't allow me to return anything not even with super.

     if (attachments) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.attach).setEnabled(!attachments);
            
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

Comment: Post your code about `attachments` also.

Comment: You were right it was my fault. I simply did a copy and not a cut and the return statement was there! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Unreachable Statement` is because you're trying to do stuff after the function already returned. That code can never be reached. Try:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.attach).setEnabled(attachments);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Georgy Gobozov solved my problem but anyway thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the comments. :)